# Commerce Feeds failing to import due to missing bundle property

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting, commerce

I have a fresh install of Commerce Kickstart, and using the Commerce Feeds module to import my list of products from a CSV.  I mapped my fields (sku, title_field, commerce_price:amount, field_commerce_saleprice:amount, and product_id) to the fields in my csv.  I am using a CSV parser, File upload, and attaching it to a standalone form.  When I process the import of either 1 item, or my full list (474 items), none of them import due to the following error:

```
Missing bundle property on entity of type commerce_product
```

Here is the entity from the log:

```
Entity

(object) array(
  'type' => 'product',
  'product_id' => '588',
  'is_new' => FALSE,
  'sku' => '052-001-014588',
  'uid' => '1',
  'status' => 1,
  'created' => 1447383612,
  'changed' => 1447383612,
  'log' => 'Created by FeedsCommerceProductProcessor',
  'revision_timestamp' => 1447383612,
  'revision_uid' => '1',
  'original' => FALSE,
  'title_original' => '',
)
```

I can't seem to figure out why they won't process and import.  Can anyone help?  Let me know what information you'd like to see.

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently this may be an issue inside of the importer, but what is happening was I was trying to map `product_id` on to `product_id` when there was no such field within the product itself that was mappable.